# How to obtain tags assigned to cloudformation stack using boto3?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-sdk, aws-cloudformation, boto3

I am trying to get tags and their values which are assigned to cloudformation stack on my aws account using Boto3. I am able to retrieve the list of all the cloudformation stacks, output and other attributes but not able to retrieve tags.

Answer (score 3):

According to the [API documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/APIReference/API_Stack.html) the describe-stacks endpoint has a `Tags` field, which is a list of objects containing a `Key` and `Value` field. Boto exposes these:

https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/cloudformation.html#CloudFormation.Client.describe_stacks

If `response.Stacks[*].Tags` is an empty list then your stack has no tags.